# Convert .pem file to .ppk file in aws using putty

Tags: aws-cli

Why do we need to convert .pem file to .ppk file in aws to get access of server from putty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PuTTY doesn't natively support the private key format (.pem) generated
>   by Amazon EC2. You must convert your private key into a .ppk file
>   before you can connect to your instance using PuTTY. You can use the
>   PuTTYgen tool for this conversion. This tool, available for both
>   Windows and Unix operating system, can convert keys.

See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/convert-pem-file-into-ppk/